# word separated with single space character from bash output

Tags: regex, linux, ubuntu, mono

I am trying to separate result of bash output using regex.

for instance

```
systemd+   531  0.0  0.0 100272   232 ?        Ssl  Jan26   0:08 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root       675  0.0  0.0  28660  1884 ?        Ss   Jan26   0:13 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+   735  0.0  0.0  43712  2692 ?        Ss   Jan26   0:37 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

in above output, I want to convert each into a result object.

how can I use regex to split result into separate token 
I am able to use this 
reg ex to separate words. but I can see in Linux almost all the time \t or multiple spaces are used to separate each column

this regex provides correct result fo

```
[\w-:]+

systemd+   531  0.0  0.0 100272   232 ?        Ssl  Jan26   0:08 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

Raw Match Pattern:

```
[\w-:]+
```

$matches Array:

```
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => systemd
             [1] => 531
             [2] => 0.0
             [3] => 0.0
             [4] => 100272
             [5] => 232
             [6] => Ssl
             [7] => Jan26
             [8] => 0:08
             [9] => /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
         )

 )
```

however it does not work for below line

```
systemd+   1183  0.0  0.0  42624   256 ?        Ss   Jan26   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

$matches Array:

```
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => systemd
             [1] => 1183
             [2] => 0.0
             [3] => 0.0
             [4] => 42624
             [5] => 256
             [6] => Ss
             [7] => Jan26
             [8] => 0:00
             [9] => /lib/systemd/systemd
             [10] => --user
         )

 )
```

match 9 and 10 should be together.

Comment: Why not just split on whitespace `\s+` ??

Comment: Usually though `\w-:` is an invalid character range. What engine did you run this on?

Comment: I am not familiar with Mono/.NET, but I am pretty sure, you can limit the number of result fields.

Comment: [\w:\?\/\+]+\s+


             [0] => systemd+   
             [1] => 1183  
             [2] => 0  
             [3] => 0  
             [4] => 42624   
             [5] => 256 
             [6] => ?        
             [7] => Ss   
             [8] => Jan26   
             [9] => 0:00 
             [10] => /lib/systemd/systemd

Comment: what I really want is ability to query 
ps aux  and 
dpkg -l <name> 
results into mono to determine success or failure